# Error in PHP code unexpected "$agent"

Tags: php

I am getting the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$agent' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webconcept2.php on line 3

and the code is given below.
I have checked all possible errors of semicolons etc but does not find the error

```
<?php

 $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/Linux/i',$agent)) $os = 'Linux';
  elseif(preg_match('/Mac/i',$agent)) $os = '/Mac';
  elseif(preg_match('/iPhone/i',$agent)) $os = 'iPhone';
  elseif(preg_match('/iPad/i',$agent)) $os = 'iPad';
  elseif(preg_match('/Droid/i',$agent)) $os = 'Droid';
  elseif(preg_match('/Unix/i',$agent)) $os = 'Unix';
  elseif(preg_match('/Windows/i',$agent)) $os = 'Windows';
  elseif $os = 'Unknown';
     // Browser Detection
if(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$agent)) $br = 'Firefox';
    elseif(preg_match('Mac/i',$agent)) $br = 'Mac';
    elseif(preg_match('Chrome/i',$agent)) $br = 'Chrome';
    elseif(preg_match('Opera/i',$agent)) $br = 'opera';
    elseif(preg_match('MSIE/i',$agent)) $br = 'IE';
    else $bs = 'Unknown';

?>
```

Comment: first error is elseif $os = 'Unknown';, it is not elseif, it's a else statement

Comment: Replace elseif $os = 'Unknown'; to else $os = 'Unknown';

Comment: Is `$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` the line with the error?  If so - it's most likely the code above it.  If not then try and indicate in the code which line the error is on.

Comment: @saravana done that but error is still the same

Comment: @BhumiShah corrected that mistake but error is still there

Comment: @NigelRen error is possibly in this line but also it is the first line of the code

Comment: But it says line 9, which leads me to think there is something above it.

Comment: @NigelRen above it there is only <?php. Actaually what happened, above it there was only spaces, <html> and <body> which i have delete now

Comment: @NigelRen i corrected it, now it shows error in line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your last elseif statement in your checks for os detection, you are missing a condition `elseif (condition)`.

What you meant to do is

```
else $os = 'Unknown';
```

Also, in your checks for browser detection, your regular expressions are not correct. `elseif(preg_match('Mac/i',$agent))`. It should be `'/Mac/i'`

Comment: Done that. But error is still there and same